# MSVS(2012) per-user per-project settings (propertry sheets)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, project, projects-and-solutions

`Microsoft.LANGUAGE.PLATFORM.user.props` already allows to define user-specific project propertries. But I need to set different user-specific options for different projects, preferably witout messing with either environment variables or conditional macro.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am just adding `User.props` on per-project basis without adding it to repository. Thus my teammates must create `User.props` manually and fill it with settings.

This method feels clumsy and hacky a bit, so I am hoping to find better approach.